# Why don't I have to declare that x is reusable/duplicable with affine semantics and function types?

Tags: rust, logic, move-semantics, type-theory, formal-semantics

I was told that Rust has a semantics in affine logic -- so one has deletion/weakening but not duplication/contraction.

The following compiles:

```
fn throw_away<A, B>(x: A, _y: B) -> A {
    x
}
```

Because duplication is disallowed, the following does not compile:

```rust
fn dup<A>(x: A) -> (A, A) {
    (x, x)
}
```

Similarly, neither of these compile:

```rust
fn throw_away3<A, B>(x: A, f: fn(A) -> B) -> A {
    x;
    f(x)
}

fn throw_away4<A, B>(x: A, f: fn(A) -> B) -> A {
    throw_away(x, f(x))
}
```

Weakening is also witnessable

```rust
fn weaken<A, B, C>(f: fn(A) -> B) -> impl Fn(A, C) -> B {
    move |x: A, y: C| f(x)
}
```

Instead of returning `fn(A, C) -> B`, we returned `impl Fn(A, C) -> B`.  Is there a way to return `fn(A, C) -> B` instead?  It's fine if not; I'm just curious.

Something else I expect is that you can lift `A` to `() -> A`.  However, functions in Rust can be duplicated and used more than once.  For example,

```rust
fn app_twice(f: fn(A) -> A, x: A) -> A {
    f(f(x))
}
```

Suppose there was actually a function `lift(x: A) -> fn() -> A`, then we could break the move semantics. For example, this would allow

```rust
fn dup_allowed(x: A) -> (A, A) {
    let h = lift(x);
    (h(), h())
}
```

Thus to lift `A` to `fn() -> A`, we need to know that the function is "linear/affine" or can be used only once.  Rust provides a type for this: `FnOnce() -> A`.  In the following, the first compiles, and the second does not.

```rust
fn app_once(f: impl FnOnce(A) -> A, x: A) -> A {
    f(x)
}

fn app_twice2(f: impl FnOnce(A) -> A, x: A) -> A {
    f(f(x))
}
```

The following functions are inverses of each other (probably, I don't know Rust's semantics well enough to say that they are actually inverse to each other):

```rust
fn lift_up<A>(x: A) -> impl FnOnce() -> A {
    move || x
}

fn lift_up_r<A>(f: impl FnOnce() -> A) -> A {
    f()
}
```

Since `fn dup<A>(x: A) -> (A, A) { (x,x) }` does not compile, I thought that the following might be a problem:

```rust
fn dup<A>(x: fn() -> A) -> (A, A) {
    (x(), x())
}
```

It seems that Rust is doing something special for `fn(A) -> B` types.

Why don't I have to declare that x is reusable/duplicable in the above?

Perhaps something different is going on.  Declared functions are a bit special `fn f(x: A) -> B { ... }` is a particular witness that `A -> B`.  Thus if `f` needs to be used multiple times, it can be reproved as many times as needed, but `fn(A) -> B` is a completely different thing: it is not a constructed thing but a hypothetical thing, and must be using that `fn(A) -> B`s are duplicatable.  In fact, I've been thinking that it's more like a freely duplicable entity.  Here's my rough analogy:

- `fn my_fun<A,B>(x :A) -> B { M }`  "is" x:A |- M:B
- `fn(A) -> B` "is" !(A -o B) hence freely duplicable
- Thus `fn() -> A` "is" !(() -o A) = !A hence `fn () -> A` is the (co)free duplication on A
- `fn dup_arg<A: Copy>(x: A) -> B { M }` "says" that A has duplication or is a comonoid
- `impl FnOnce (A) -> B` "is" A -o B

But this can't be right...  For what is `impl Fn(A) -> B`?  From playing around a bit, it seems that `fn(A) -> B` is more strict than `Fn(A) -> B`.  What am I missing?

Comment: You can duplicate `fn`s at will because they are `Copy`, meaning they hold only trivially cloneable information, just like, say, numbers. A `fn` is just the address of the function in the executable, and copying it only entail duplicating the pointer. This is not the case with closures, which may capture arbitrary state, as your `lift` example does.

Comment: Thanks!  When I declare a function at the top level like fn my_fun(x:A) ... then is rust treating references to my_fun as addresses/pointers in the same way that it's treating fn(A) -> B passed in as an argument to a function?

Comment: `fn(...)` are always simple references to global data. Types that implement the `Fn(...)` trait, though, don't need to be. If you pass an `fn()` to _generic_ code (that can work with any `Fn`, not just a concrete `fn`), then inside generic code you can't duplicate them unless you explicitly specify `+ Copy` (in which case the function returned by `lift` won't qualify). `impl Fn(...)` is an anonymous type only known to implement the `Fn(...)` trait. Your question was actually a very interesting read, but I'm not sure what the actual question is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```rust
> fn weaken<A, B, C>(f: fn(A) -> B) -> impl Fn(A, C) -> B {
>     move |x: A, y: C| f(x)
> }
> ```
>
> Instead of returning `fn(A, C) -> B,` we returned `impl Fn(A, C) -> B`. Is there a way to return `fn(A, C) -> B` instead? It's fine if not; I'm just curious.

No, because a `fn` is by definition not a closure: it cannot contain any state that wasn't compiled into the program (in this case, the value of `f`). This is closely related to your next observation: *because* a `fn` cannot close over anything, it trivially cannot contain any non-`Copy` types and therefore can always be called multiple times, or itself copied, without violating the properties we're discussing.

Precisely: all `fn(..) -> _` types implement `Fn` and `Copy` (as well as `FnOnce`).

- `Copy` is the *marker trait* ('marker' meaning it provides no methods) that has the special purpose of telling the compiler that it is free to copy the bits of a type automatically whenever it is used more than once. Anything implementing `Copy` is opting out of the move-but-not-copy system -- but can't thereby violate the non-Copy-ness of a *different* type.
- `Fn` is the trait for functions that can be called *by immutable reference* (not modifying or consuming the function itself). This is in principle separate from `Copy`, but it's very similar in effect; the differences that one could end up with (some of these can't happen in ordinary code) are:

  - If a function implements `Fn` but not `Copy` or `Clone`, then you can't *store* the function multiple places but you can call it as many times as you want.
  - If a function implements `Copy` but not `Fn` (only `FnOnce`), then this is invisible because every call of it (except for the last) implicitly copies it.
  - If a function implements `Clone` but not `Fn` or `Copy`, then you would have to `.clone()` it each time you called it (except the last).

---

> And indeed the following functions are inverses of eachother (probably, I don't know rust's semantics well enough to say that they are actually inverse to each other):
>
> ```rust
> fn lift_up<A> (x:A) -> impl FnOnce () -> A {move | | x}
> fn lift_up_r<A> (f : impl FnOnce () -> A) -> A {f()}
> ```

`lift_up_r` accepts functions that `lift_up` did not produce; for example, if `f` has a side effect, panics, or hangs then `let f = lift_up(lift_up_r(f));` has that effect. Ignoring that, they are inverses. An even better pair of inverses without that caveat would be functions for moving a value into a `struct` and back out -- which this is effectively doing, except for allowing inputs that aren't of that particular struct type.

---

> Since `fn dup (x:A) -> (A,A) {(x,x)}` does not compile, I thought that the following might be a problem:
>
> ```rust
> fn dup<A> (x : fn() -> A) -> (A,A) {(x(),x()}
> ```
>
> But it seems that rust is doing something special for fn(A) -> B types. Finally, my question: why don't I have to declare that x is reusable/duplicable in the above?

When you have a generic function with a type variable, `fn dup<A>`, the compiler makes no assumptions about the properties of `A` (except that it is `Sized` unless you opt out of that implicit bound, because working with non-`Sized` values is highly restrictive and usually not what you want). In particular, it does not assume that `A` implements `Copy`.

On the other hand, as I mentioned above, all `fn` types implement `Fn` and `Copy`, so they can always be duplicated and reused.

The way to write a `dup` function which operates on general functions and *fails to compile* in the way you expect is:

```rust
fn dup<A, F>(x: F) -> (A,A)
where
    F: FnOnce() -> A
{
    (x(),x())
}
```

Here, we tell the compiler that `F` is a type of function which is consumed by calling it, and don't tell it about any way to duplicate `F`. So, it fails to compile with "error[E0382]: use of moved value: `x`". The shortest way to make this compile would be to add the bound `F: Copy`, and the most general would be to add `F: Clone` and an explicit `.clone()` call.

---

> Perhaps something different is going on. Declared functions are a bit special fn f(x:A) -> B {...} is a particular witness that A -> B. Thus if f needs to be used multiple times, it can be reproved as many times as needed. But fn(A) -> B is a completely different thing: it is not a constructed thing but a hypothetical thing, and must be using a that fn(A) -> Bs are duplicatable. In fact, I've been thinking that it's more like a freely duplicable entity.

I'm no logician, but I think that the first half of this is not correct. In particular, (outside of some irrelevant considerations about generics) there are no properties that "a declared function" has that an arbitrary value of type `fn(A) -> B` does not have. Rather, the value of type `fn(A) -> B` *can be copied*, and that copiability corresponds directly to the fact that "it can be reproved", because (until we start introducing ideas like JIT code generation) every *value* of type `fn(A) -> B` refers to a *compiled piece of code* (and no other data) -- and hence a lemma that the compiler has checked and given the program license to reuse it as many times as needed *at run time.*

> For what is impl Fn(A) -> B? From playing around a bit, it seems that fn(A) -> B is more strict than Fn(A) -> B. What am I missing?

The `impl` syntax serves different roles, but in argument position it is almost exactly a shorthand for generics. If I write

```rust
fn foo<A, B>(f: impl Fn(A) -> B) {}
```

then that is equivalent to

```rust
fn foo<A, B, F>(f: F) 
where
   F: Fn(A) -> B
{}
```

except that the caller is not allowed to specify any of the parameters when any `impl` argument types exist (this is not relevant to your interests but I mention it for accuracy). Thus, we're telling the compiler that `F` can be *anything* as long as it is callable as a reusable function. In particular, we're not specifying `F: Copy` or `F: Clone`. `fn(A) -> B`, on the other hand, is a concrete type which implements `Fn(A) -> B` *and* `Copy`, so you get that for free.

In return position, `fn ... -> impl Fn(A) -> B`, the `impl` denotes an *existential type:* you're asserting that *there exists some type implementing `Fn`* which the function will return. The compiler tracks the concrete type in order to generate code, but your program avoids naming it. This is necessary when returning a closure, but optional when returning a function that does not close over anything: for example, you can write

```rust
fn foo<A>() -> fn(A) -> A {
    |x| x
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the amazing and detailed reply!  One thing I'm confused by is that every fn(A) -> B is a compile time constant.  This is a really neat property!  Is this because fn(A) -> B is just a pointer and at compile time is given a constant address?  Suppose we we  write a function "fn w<A> (x:i32) -> fn(A) -> A {...}" where if x <0 it's "|x| x" and otherwise is something like "|x| while(true){}x".  Then in some other function generic over A we could have some variable "y:i32" and then "let h : fn(A) -> A = w(y); ...".  In that case is h deduced to be a constant?

Comment: I'm going to wait till tomorrow to accept your answer so that I can set a bounty and award  it.  I'm  grateful for your answer and your patience with my novice and boring question.

Comment: @JonathanGallagher "Is this because fn(A) -> B is just a pointer and at compile time is given a constant address?" — The address is not strictly a compile time constant because it may be modified (in fact, is likely randomized) by the operating system's program loader/dynamic linker — but it won't change over the lifetime of the process. But those are all more or less implementation details; the important thing is that the definition of the `fn` type includes that it implements `Copy`, and the system does what is necessary to ensure that.

Comment: *wait till tomorrow to accept your answer so that I can set a bounty and award it* @JonathanGallagher you can award a bounty even if a question has been answered / accepted.